# Is cash(currency) a security and a debt instrument?

Tags: financial-economics, definition

I know that cash is a financial asset and securities are defined as tradable financial assets, so cash is a security, right?

Another thing I'm wondering is that whether cash/banknote is a debt instrument or not. [On wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_(finance)) it is defined as one of a debt securities.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think cash could be described as a security... one of the characteristics of securities is that they have imperfect (if very high) liquidity and provide a return (be it fixed or variable). Cash is the definition of liquid and inherently provides no return - you could earn interest on cash by depositing it in a bank but then you are creating a debt obligation in effect - the cash inherently, as in cash in a physical safe, generates zero return nominal by definition. You could think of cash as a debt security where a debt is theoretically placed on the issuer. But: in practice the debt is impossible to pay. You cannot bring a bill into the fed and demand they honour it. So I suppose it would be a debt security in the theoretical sense but it lacks almost all properties of debt securities:
cannot be repaid in practice, never intended to be repaid, perfectly liquid etc, and it has a value that cannot be expressed in terms of anything but itself.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a lawyer, but my understanding is, as a matter of US law, cash is not a security because it is explicitly exempted under [The Securities Exchange Act of 1934](http://white-summers.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/SECURITIES-LAW-4-23-13-v.1.pdf):

> The term ‘‘security’’ means any note, stock, treasury stock, security
>   future, security-based swap, bond, debenture, certificate of interest
>   or participation in any profit-sharing agreement or in any oil, gas,
>   or other mineral royalty or lease, any collateral-trust certificate,
>   preorganization certificate or subscription, transferable share,
>   investment contract, voting-trust certificate, certificate of deposit
>   for a security, any put, call, straddle, option, or privilege on any
>   security, certificate of deposit, or group or index of securities
>   (including any interest therein or based on the value thereof), or any
>   put, call, straddle, option, or privilege entered into on a national
>   securities exchange relating to foreign currency, or in general, any
>   instrument commonly known as a ‘‘security’’; or any certificate of
>   interest or participation in, temporary or interim certificate for,
>   receipt for, or warrant or right to subscribe to or purchase, any of
>   the foregoing; **but shall not include currency or any note, draft,
>   bill of exchange, or banker’s acceptance which has a maturity at the
>   time of issuance of not exceeding nine months, exclusive of days of
>   grace, or any renewal thereof the maturity of which is likewise
>   limited**.

SECURITIES EXCHANGE ACT OF 1934, Section 3, Part 10